# Wrap table with DIV tag ?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I Have a table in my html page, it's be default not shown on my page... but when a user click on something in the page it appear

i want to wrap the table with a div container, i used the following for doing that :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$('table').wrap('<div id="table" />');      

});
```

but it still doesn't wrap the table when it appear.. it think the problem that i used the dom ready, how can make the div to wrap the table when it appear on my page

thanks

Comment: It should work but try changing `document` to `window` and `ready` to `load` and let us know if the problem still persist.

Comment: `... but when a user click on something` make it clear how you are showing table?

Comment: @jai it's just a regular table .. i want to add div around it to make `overflow: scroll` as it can't be done on table

Answer (score 0):

use this in the click event..

> when a user click on something

after the table is created and  not on `document.ready`.
since  when `document.ready` is called it won't be able to find the dynamically added `<table>` ..

example..

```
$('#something').click(function()){
   //your codes crete table
   $('table').wrap('<div id="table" />'); 
}
```

Comment: OK is there any function to monitor the html when there is a html dynamically added to the page

Comment: As i don't bind it with a click event

Comment: for that i need to see the codes that you used  ...can u post that??

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if($('table').length){
       $('table').wrap('<div id="table" />');      
    }else{
       alert('No tables found on the page.');
    }
});
```

and you can do this with `.load()` handler too:

```
 jQuery(document).load(function($) {
    if($('table').length){
       $('table').wrap('<div id="table" />');      
    }else{
       alert('No tables found on the page.');
    }
});
```

Comment: it still doesn't work and i put `if($('table').length == 1)` also it doesn't work